# Warning: 'LPEVENT CItem::m_pkExpireEvent' and warning:format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'double'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I almost done with all errors, thanks to community and all his members.

In this post i will try to include all remaining errors.

1. `warning: unused variable 'sum'`:

   ```
   if (!m_pTable->GetDragonHeartExtValues(ds_type, grade_idx, vec_chargings, vec_probs))
   {
       return false;
   }

   int idx = Gamble(vec_probs);

   float sum = 0.f;
   if (-1 == idx)
   {
       sys_err ("Gamble is failed. ds_type(%d), grade_idx(%d)", ds_type, grade_idx);
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. `warning: NULL used in arithmetic`:

   ```
   const char * line = two_arguments(value_string, db_host[0], sizeof(db_host[0]), db_user[0], sizeof(db_user[0]));
   line = two_arguments(line, db_pwd[0], sizeof(db_pwd[0]), db_db[0], sizeof(db_db[0]));

   if (NULL != line[0])
   {
       char buf[256];
       one_argument(line, buf, sizeof(buf));
       str_to_number(mysql_db_port[0], buf);
   }
   ```
3. `warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type`:

   ```
   int j = 1;

   do
   {
       BYTE p = wCell + (DRAGON_SOUL_BOX_COLUMN_NUM * j);

       if (p >= DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM)
           return false;
       if (m_pointsInstant.bItemGrid[p])
           if (m_pointsInstant.wDSItemGrid[p] != iExceptionCell)
               return false;
   }
   while (++j < bSize);

   return true;
   ```
4. `warning: control reaches end of non-void function`
5. `format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'double'`:

   ```
   sprintf(buf, "dice(%d) prob(%d)", fDice, fProb);
   ```

Sorry if it is not allowed to ask more than one question, but even if I wait 90 minutes and ask after, the end is the same, hopefully that he is positive.

Comment: What help do you need with this? Please be explicit,

Comment: `%d` is for integers, not for `double` values, so what you're bothering about actually?!? OT: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Comment: So, it don't do anything? Sorry but i don't understand your question.

Comment: Alternatively: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know how much code to show, this errors are displayed during the compilation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you declared a `sum` variable that you are not using anywhere, so you can get rid of it.
2. `line[0]` is a `char`, not a pointer, so use `0` or `'\0'` instead of NULL.
3. you are comparing a variable against a value that is outside the valid range of values for the variable's data type.  Given the code you showed, that means either `DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM` is larger than 255, or `bSize` is smaller than an `int`, or the like.
4. the function has a non-void return type, but the compiler detected a path in the flow of the function's code that can cause it to skip returning a value.
5. self explanatory.  When calling `sprintf()`, you are specifying a `double` (the `fProb` variable) where an `int` is expected.  To format a `double` value, you have to use on of the floating type specifiers, such as `%lf`.  The `%d` specifier is for an `int` value instead.